# Azure Custom script extension for Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, azure

I am trying to provision and configure a Linux VM on Windows Azure with the following command:

```
$PublicConfiguration = '{"fileUris":["http://path/deployment/ubuntu-elasticsearch-installation.sh"], "commandToExecute": "sh ./ubuntu-elasticsearch-installation.sh -n Node1 -n Node2 -c cluster"}'
```

The script works when I execute it on any Linux VM in the same format. But when i do this only the -c parameter is passed to the script during provisioning.

On the other hand when I do it this way just for test (the script taked parameters and installs them):

```
$PublicConfiguration ='{"fileUris":["http://path/deployment/test.sh"], "commandToExecute": "sh test.sh apache2 unzip"}'
```

it installs both.

Then I do the following for both:

```
$ExtensionName = 'CustomScriptForLinux'  
$Publisher = 'Microsoft.OSTCExtensions'  
$Version = '1.2' 
$vm = Set-AzureVMExtension -ExtensionName $ExtensionName -VM $vm -Publisher $Publisher -Version $Version -PublicConfiguration $PublicConfiguration
New-AzureVM -ServiceName $servicename -Location $location -VMs $vm
```

Does anyone have experience with Custom Scripts for Linux?

Thanks,
Vangel